# Fill fields on a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, macros, autofill

I've already asked this question, but it's still too unclear to me, and it seems people haven't understood what I'm trying to do, so I'll try and be clearer.

This website: https://www4.polymtl.ca/poly/poly.html
is the website I want to fill.

What I would like to be able to do, is modify the values of the "nip", "code", and "naissance" fields with text (for example, code being "majuif").

```
    <input type=password name=code size=8 maxlength=8>
    <input type=password name=nip size=8 maxlength=8>
    <input type=password name=naissance size=8 maxlength=8>
```

However, I don't know how to do that. And this is my problem.

Should I write another HTML file - I don't know if the word "macro" can be used for that, but I'm pretty sure it can - and insert JavaScript in it?

Please note that I'm not a professional in JavaScript or HTML, but I have basics, and still learning.

Thanks,

-Max.

Comment: What is the end result you want to achieve with this? Do you want to run this on a local computer?

Comment: Ok, so you have stated the following:

1. I have 3 fields on a page
2. I want to fill the 3 fields with data

We need to know when this is supposed to occur:
eg. I want the fields to be populated automatically when the page loads or I want the fields to be loaded when a button is clicked...etc.

It would be helpful to know what the data is you want to fill. As en example: I want to fill the code field with a default value when user reaches the page through a specific link.

Comment: The webpage doesn't change. All i want is to FILL those inputs (to which I have no access, because it's not MY webpage (I have no access to the sourcecode)) with values (random stuff at first, then my real info) - to be able to log in on the website.

Comment: @MajuiF - You want to inject values into a form on a site that you have opened in a browser and does not belong to you. And as far as I can see you do not have experience in any development languages - Am I correct?

Comment: @Julian - Wrong. I'm familiar with C/C++/C# and Java. I, however, never studied HTML or JavaScript in class (or barely). I'm in 3rd year of Software Engineering.

Comment: @MajuiF - Didn't mean to upset you, was just trying to understand how to best help you. Good luck with your studies and enjoy life.

Comment: @Julian - I'm not upset, just wanted to let you know I wasn't a total begginer :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looked at your other question and you said it is not your page. You can not read or write to a page which is not created by your own page.

You can from your own browser create a shortcut / bookmark link to javascript:alert('hello world'); or

```
javascript:document.getElementByName('code').value = 'majuif';
document.getElementByName('nip').value = 'majuif';
document.getElementByName('naissance').value = 'majuif';
```

Then hit the bookmark when you have the page in your browswer.

***Update***

Checked it needs to be getElementsByName plural but still not happy about their html does not find the input named code - getElementsByTagName works

```
javascript:document.getElementsByTagName('input')[1].value='code';document.getElementsByTagName('input')[2].value='nip';document.getElementsByTagName('input')[3].value='naissance';alert('tested');
```

Note you can cut and paste the script into the address bar when you are on the page.

Comment: It works with the "alert" - a popup window appears - but it doesn't work with the getElementByName - nothing gets filled (nothing happens at all). I added a new bookmark linking to your code, but I can't get it to work. Just to make sure, do I have to change the name "document" in your variables? If not, I don't know why it doesn't work :/ But great help, thanks.